# restore form content when leaving and going back web page

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having a problem with firefox and a form web page. The same problem does not occur with chrome.
When the user submits the form with required fields empty an error page is shown with a "go back"-button.
If the User goes back the form is empty in firefox.

Now I want to ensure that this does not happen.
I found this code:
[How to keep changed form content when leaving and going back to HTTPS page? (works with HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420624/how-to-keep-changed-form-content-when-leaving-and-going-back-to-https-page-wor)

But I do not understand how to get it working.

I also found this 
[Mozilla Firefox form values reset on history.back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664904/mozilla-firefox-form-values-reset-on-history-back)

Which is basically a copy of my question, but I need a full working example of the proposed solution "*capture your POST data and turn it into SESSION variables, then repopulate input fields on browser back*".

Here a webpage for testing that show the code in use:
http://s659173456.online.de/

However it does not show the problem in firefox nor chrome. Nevertheless I want to include a restorage of the input values using session variables.

EDIT:
I added a session restorage:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
....
<input class="flatinput" type="text" size="40" name="Nachname" 
    value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['Nachname']) ? $_SESSION['Nachname'].'restored' : ''); ?>"
/>
```

and in the php file for the evaluation

```
function process_anmeldeformular() { 

// save POST as SESSION
if(isset($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        if( ($val != "submit") && !empty($val) ) {
            $_SESSION["$key"] = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

But that does not solve the problem.

Comment: The accepted answer on the first question you have linked provides several options with pros and cons, all the code for each one and working jsfiddle examples.

Comment: And I included the code and it is not working for me...

Comment: If you had provided a simple example that works in Chrome, and not in Firefox, then we would have had something to work on. Now I don't really know how to help you.

Comment: I created a dummy site for the code, but it does not show the problem in contrast to the real site. Nevertheless I want to restore the session variable in this code. Link added to the question.